# php функция mail() некорректно работает

Tags: php, email

Пытаюсь наладить обратную связь на сайте. Отсылаю, введенные пользователями, данные на свою почту. Вот стандартный пример отправки имейла, который я беру за основу:

```
mail("nobody@example.com", "the subject", $message,
     "From: webmaster@example.com \r\n" . "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());
```

Проблема в том, что если в качестве имейла в секции `From` указан имейл типа `...@mail.ru`, то письма не доходят. В принципе, эту проблему можно обойти, но все же, для общего кругозора, хотелось бы знать, почему так происходит.

Comment: возможно mail.ru находится в черном списке почтового сервера получателя. Проверьте при отправку с указанием другого адреса. + при этом провертье какое значение возвращает функция `mail()`

Comment: С других адресов все письма доходят. Возвращает функция во всех случаях true. Письм с мэйл.ру не доходят совсем, даже не попадают в спам.

Answer (score 1):

функция `mail` использует `sendmail` или другие и шлет с уже настроенных ящиков (через `sendmail`). Если адрес отправки фактический не совпадает с полем FROM то скорее всего это спам и большинство систем или не принимают такое или пихают сразу в спам.

В php лучше использовать библиотеку [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) или уметь самому нормально настраивать `sendmail` в `linux`

Answer (score 1):

Письма, в которых, в качестве обратных адресов указываются почтовые ящики большинства общедоступных сервисов, скорее всего не дойдут, если отправлялись они без использования их собственных почтовых серверов. Для того, чтобы письма в небольших количествах гарантированно доходили до адресата, используйте SMTP, либо почту на собственном домене (для этого не забудьте указать соответствующую [SPF-запись](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework)).